# Feed Me Plugin - Prevent Feed from Being Triggered Multiple Times in Quick Succession

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-feedme, events, guzzle

I’d like to prevent a feedme feed from running more than once when multiple requests are received within a few seconds of each other.

My first guess is that I would want to target an event such as ‘’’BeforeFetchFeed’’’ to determine when to prevent the feed from being parsed.

Another more lo-fi option may be to use the Guzzle option ‘’’Delay’’’ and setting the value to increase after each subsequent run. Would this be possible in the config options?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cancel a FeedMe job before it starts by invalidating the `EVENT_BEFORE_PROCESS_FEED` event in the `Process` class. In your case, it sounds like you want to check whether the Feed is already in the queue, so from within a module you could do something like this:

```php
Event::on(Process::class, Process::EVENT_BEFORE_PROCESS_FEED, function(FeedProcessEvent $event)
  {
    $existingJob = 0;
    foreach(array_column(Craft::$app->queue->jobInfo, 'description') as $index => $string) {
      if (strpos($string, $event->feed->name) !== FALSE) {
        ++$existingJob;
        if ($existingJob > 1) {
          $event->isValid = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```